# Redirect to login page after session timeout

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, session-timeout

I have found some similar questions but none gave me what I really need.

Here is the thing, I have added this to my `web.config` to handle user session expiration:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" />
```

After 1 minute, the `Session_End` event from `Global.asax` is raised:

```
Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
End Sub
```

This doesn't work, because:

```
Response is not available in this context.
```

(By the way, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264421/how-to-redirect-to-home-page-after-session-timeout/6264446#6264446) got an anwswer telling that this is ok and it got upvotes).

I don't want nothing fancy. I just want a simple way to redirect the user to the login page when the session time expires. That's all.

Thank you.

Comment: Try HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")

Comment: If you have the login properly registered the user should be redirected to login with any post.  As a user I don't want to lose the page I am on because the session timed out.

Comment: That won't work too @Tim. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Blam, what do you mean by a "properly registered" login?

Comment: I don't remember all the steps but for sure  my production application works that way as I load data and my my login often expires.  If it sent me to another page and I could not see if my load finished I would not like that. In ASP.NET you mark it as the login page and can't remember if I had to also mark it in IIS.  I do recall I had to mark the Defaul page in both the ASP.NET project and IIS.

Comment: Are you using MembershipServices?   If not never mind.  Or think about using MemberShipServices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session_End is a **server-side** event, meaning it is triggered on the web server and has nothing to do with a request by the client. This is why the Request is unavailable.

You have two choices in this matter:

1. On each client request, check if a specific Session variable is set. If it is not, it means the previous Session has expired and the new Session must be populated. (I am assuming this is why you want to check for Session expiration)
2. Have a javascript call on the client that periodically goes back to the server to check if the Session is still valid. If the Session has expired, you can redirect the user to the login page.

samples of different redirect methods

```
location.href = "login.aspx";
// or you can use 
location.assign("login.aspx");
//for redirecting without storing in history
location.replace("login.aspx")
```

Don't forget to add `?ReturnUrl=[current url]` to the login redirect path.

HTH

Comment: When you make call to server from client using javascript or by any means, it will renew the session always. So above approaches will never work.

Comment: It will not **renew** the session, it will create a new one. So if your previous session had a flag set, the newly created session will not have the flag set.

Comment: @ShaiCohen Your comment directly contradicts #2. If the check interval is less than the session timeout, it will update the last accessed time of the existing session and timeout will never be possible as Jitendra said. If your check interval is greater than the session timeout, then what you mentioned in your comment may work, but the user will not be warned that their session is about to expire; it will have already expired.

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

You can use the `Page_Init`event in the `global.asax`

#### Sample

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 If Context.Session IsNot Nothing Then
  If Session.IsNewSession Then
   Dim newSessionIdCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("ASP.NET_SessionId")
   If newSessionIdCookie IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim newSessionIdCookieValue As String = newSessionIdCookie.Value
    If newSessionIdCookieValue <> String.Empty Then
     ' This means Session was timed Out and New Session was started
     Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
    End If
   End If
  End If
 End If
End Sub
```

#### More Information

- [Detecting Session Timeout And Redirect To Login Page In ASP.NET](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/11/detecting-session-timeout-and-redirect.html)

Comment: Well, I've copied this code to my Global.asax and put a breakpoint on it. When the session expires, Session_End is raised but Page_Init no.

Comment: Yes but at the next request, the method should called. The problem is that the server knows that the session has expired, but in HTTP (which is no permanent connection) you cant do something with the client. You only can do something if the user does a request.

Comment: If you want you can keep the session alive if you do a request from the client to the server using javascript every x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Check for expired sessions on every Page_Init event. If there are too many pages to do this check, this is what I usually do:

- I create a base class and inherit from System.Web.UI.Page.
- Write my redirect logic in the Page_Init event of my base class.
- Have the rest of my pages inherit from this base class.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the C# version of [dknaack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502326/1264804):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Session != null)
    {
        if (Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            HttpCookie newSessionIdCookie = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
            if (newSessionIdCookie != null)
            {
                string newSessionIdCookieValue = newSessionIdCookie.Value;
                if (newSessionIdCookieValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    // This means Session was timed Out and New Session was started
                    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```