# How to Redirect page when session was expires

Tags: asp.net, session

I use following code in web config but it doesn't works properly.Suggest your code for redirect when `session` expires

my code is:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="MyAuth" timeout="60" protection="All" loginUrl="Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
```

Comment: What is "doesn't work properly"? What _does_ happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect to login page after session timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502295/redirect-to-login-page-after-session-timeout)

Comment: @CodeCaster it will show error when when i try to click an button after 20 min

Comment: We can't do anything with that information, as "an error" and "a button" doesn't tell anything. See the question linked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="WhateverYourAuthNameIs" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" protection="All" path="/" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>
```

Perfectly working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a session using Session["sessionName"] and see if it returns null and if it does just redirect them using Response.Redirect("login.aspx");

```
if(Session["sessionName"]==null)
{
   Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```