# How to redirect to some other page on session timeout in ASP.NET and test it

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, session-timeout

Applicationis developed in framework 3.5.

There is no login page. It is refers "windows" authentication in web.config file.

I want to setup - when session time out occur then it should redirect to 'specific page' and showing time out.

Can any one suggest how i could achieve this and test in development environment.

I dont' want any configuraiton on server side.

Need of only one thing- on session time out redirect to specific page and test it on development env.

I have added below line on web.config. and tried to check by keeping the site idle and then click at some button but no effect. please guide me.
     `<sessionState timeout="01" mode="InProc" cookieless="false" />`

Comment: please refer this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27073/How-to-Redirect-to-Another-Page-when-Session-Timeo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect to login page after session timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502295/redirect-to-login-page-after-session-timeout)

Comment: Is `SetTimeOut` is like iteratively execute on specified interval or will check, actually session time out then only it execute. Examle - screen has 5 control and only one control is raise server event. and screen was idle for 55 sec and when user back and giving input to the control which are not yet posted then, it will redirect to time out page....??

Answer (score 0):

Add in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="1">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: here Authentication mode="windows" as of its need.