# Different auto-redirects for different pages on timeout

Tags: c#, webforms, timeout

We use timeout and auto direct, they work well. I just wonder if it is possible to change the auto redirect page without changing config file.

For example when I'm at page X , I want it to redirect to page Y automatically when timeout occurs. It will be usual login page redirection for all other pages.

Comment: Do you mean timeout on calling something internally like a database?

Comment: Sorry you are right, I was a bit  vague there. I mean session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple articles and even threads within StackOverflow that explain redirection on timeout.

One in particular that should answer your question is:

[Redirect to login page after session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502295/redirect-to-login-page-after-session-timeout)

In this answer it redirects to Login.aspx but you can check in the page that you are interested and direct to another page.

Here is the code as it was presented in that response:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Session != null)
    {
        if (Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            HttpCookie newSessionIdCookie = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
            if (newSessionIdCookie != null)
            {
                string newSessionIdCookieValue = newSessionIdCookie.Value;
                if (newSessionIdCookieValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    // This means Session was timed Out and New Session was started
                    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```