# Redirect to controller from global.asax in mvc 4 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my code in global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }

  void Session_OnEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (Session.IsNewSession)
        //Response.RedirectToRoute("logout", "Home");

        //RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
        //routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
        //routeData.Values.Add("action", "logout");
        ////routeData.Values.Add("Summary", "Error");
        ////routeData.Values.Add("Description", ex.Message);
        //IController controller = new HomeController();
        //controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));

        // HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Home/logout");
        //Response.Redirect("~/Home/logout");

        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Home/logout");  

    }
```

i want to redirect when session end occurs after some time(1 minutes).
this is my

```
web.config(<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" />)
```

i have tried a lot of code..but not working.
when the Session_OnEnd occurs i want to redirect to Home controller.but the above code in Session_OnEnd not working any suggestion.
the error occurs in Session_OnEnd is:

```
: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyZefer.UI.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

any suggestion??
how to redirect to controller???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to login page after session timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502295/redirect-to-login-page-after-session-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol is stateless. This means that as soon as a user has requested a page (and potentially started or continued on a session by sending a cookie with a session ID) the connection is ended.

The `Session_OnEnd` method may be raised on the *server* but at that stage there is no client i.e. browser connected that you can redirect. This method is therefore only useful when you want to do some server side cleanup of an expiring session e.g. removing a database record.

I would suggest you synchronise the session time on the server with a timer in JavaScript. This timer can start when the page is loading/loaded and is obviously reset when you make another request i.e. load a new page. When the timer (`setTimeout()`) expired, it redirect the user with a `windows.Location` for instance.

See also the [MSDN Documentation `Session_OnEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx#Anchor_1).